# Need to call a view's method from within its ViewModel

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

I am new to Silverlight, but am up to my ears in some of the more intermediate/advanced stuff.

I am using MVVM, in Silverlight 5.

I have a view (we'll call it ComboView.xaml).  It has a ViewModel (we'll call it AwesomeVM)

The view contains the ViewModel, declared in the page's resources like so:

```
<local:AwesomeVM x:Key="MyAwesomeVM" />
```

and then referenced in the DataContext like so:

```
<sdk:Page.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource MyAwesomeVM}"/>
</sdk:Page.DataContext>
```

The view has a method in the codebehind, called SetupPage.  SetupPage takes in, as a parameter, an instance of its viewmodel type (AwesomeVM), like so:

```
Public Sub SetupPage(ByVal VM As AwesomeVM)
    ...
End Sub
```

Now, here's the problem:  I need to call this SetupPage() from within the ViewModel.  It seems to load the page *before* the ViewModel is able to get any of its data (I assume this is because the ViewModel uses a WCF webservice, which is an asynchronous call), and so the SetupPage()'s VM has no data, and blows up.

Is there any way to call a view's method from within its ViewModel?

Comment: Why does SetupPage (in the View) need to be called from the ViewModel? What does it do, and why can't the SetupPage method be in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.. don't do that.  First of all, the page knows about its data context, so there's no need to pass the data context into that method.  Second of all, if you can't put that method in your viewmodel, and you *need* to have it in the view-- perhaps because it does some direct manipulation of the view-- don't call it directly. Decouple it, and use messaging to get it done.

Most of the MVVM frameworks (e.g. MVVM Light) will provide a lightweight messaging platform that allows you to call methods from one component to another.  For example with MVVM Light:

In your codebehind for your page:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<SetupPageMessage>(this, SetupPage);
```

Then, in your ViewModel:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new SetupPageMessage());
```

will execute the SetupPage method on your codebehind.  There's a bit more setup that's required to get this completely wired up (like creating a SetupPageMessage class, and creating the appropriately parameterized SetupPage method in your code, but this should be a better (and more testable) approach than what you are thinking.

Comment: 'don't do that' +1. Don't try to force a synchronous programming model (calling a setup method) into an intrinsically asynchronous program (loading a view from XAML (you have a Loaded event), loading data from WS (you have a callback method)). Also +1 for messaging in this case.